# What doesn't work in my extract frames from video code?

Tags: python, opencv, spyder

I tried to write 2 very simple codes to extract specific frames from a 24FPS video: One of them to extract frames based on the frame number, and the other one to extract frames at a given frequency (i.e. 1 frame every second). I am using Anaconda to create and manage my environment, and Spyder to code.

The first one:

```
#Extract frames based on their number
import cv2

# Open the video file
video = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\\path_to_video.mp4")

# Get the total number of frames in the video
total_frames = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

# Define the frame numbers you want to extract
frame_numbers = [10, 50, 100]

# Initialize the frame counter
frame_counter = 0

# Loop over each frame of the video
while True:
    # Read the current frame
    ret, frame = video.read()
    
    # Break the loop if we've reached the end of the video
    if not ret:
        break

    # Increase the frame counter
    frame_counter += 1
    
    # If the current frame number is in the list of frame numbers to extract
    if frame_counter in frame_numbers:
        # Save the frame
        cv2.imwrite("C:\\path_to_save_frame_" + str(frame_counter) + ".jpg", frame)

# Release the video object
video.release()
```

The second one:

```
#Extract frames with a given frequency
import cv2

# Open the video file
video = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\\path_to_video.mp4")

# Get the frames per second (fps) of the video
fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

# Calculate the time interval (in milliseconds) between frames
frame_time_interval = int(1000 / fps)

# Define the time frequency (in this case, 1 second)
time_frequency = 1 * 1000

# Initialize the frame counter
frame_counter = 0

# Loop over each frame of the video
while True:
    # Read the current frame
    ret, frame = video.read()
    
    # Break the loop if we've reached the end of the video
    if not ret:
        break

    # Increase the frame counter
    frame_counter += 1
    
    # If the frame counter modulo the time frequency divided by the frame time interval is 0
    if frame_counter % int(time_frequency / frame_time_interval) == 0:
        # Save the frame
        cv2.imwrite("C:\\path_to_save_frame_" + str(frame_counter) + ".jpg", frame)


# Release the video object
video.release()
```

The problem I encounter is the following: whenever I try to run one of the codes, the program seems to be running, but it extracts no frames and outputs no error message. The command console just look like this after a few seconds:

[In 1] :
runfile('C:/path_to_code/Extract_frames_time_frequency.py', wdir='C:/path_to_directory/Stage_M2')

[In 2] :

Comment: what do you see if you add a print after your `if frame_counter` line(s)?

Comment: Did you check path to save the jpg? Are there any jpg files?

Comment: Thanks fo answering. If I add a print after after if frame_counter, I see nothing new (maybe I don't know where to look). Yes, I did check the path to the jpg files, but it is sitting empty.

Comment: debug your program using python's debugger. [tour], [ask], [mre] (contains debugging tutorial)